# Начал проходить JS, не работает код

Tags: javascript

Создается 9 кнопок и 9 блоков, каждая кнопка должна закрашивать только 1 блок. Но вместо этого у меня все 9 кнопок красят 1 блок почему так происходит? 
P.s
Все это должно находиться только в 1 функции Помогите пожалуйста 
Вот код

```js
function change_color(red, blue, black, green, pink, grey, purple, yellow, orange) {
  document.getElementById('1').style.background = red;
  document.getElementById('2').style.background = blue;
  document.getElementById('3').style.background = black;
  document.getElementById('4').style.background = green;
  document.getElementById('5').style.background = pink;
  document.getElementById('6').style.background = grey;
  document.getElementById('7').style.background = purple;
  document.getElementById('8').style.background = yellow;
  document.getElementById('9').style.background = orange;
}
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' class="container">
  <div id='1' class="nav1"></div>
  <div id='2' class="nav2"></div>
  <div id='3' class="nav3"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='4' class="nav4"></div>
  <div id='5' class="nav5"></div>
  <div id='6' class="nav6"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='7' class="nav7"></div>
  <div id='8' class="nav8"></div>
  <div id='9' class="nav9"></div>
  <br/>
  
  <button onclick="change_color('red')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('blue')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('black')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color('green')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('pink')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('grey')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color('purple')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('yellow')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('orange')">XXX</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаете аргументы, запомните аргументы это не массив `(red, blue, black, green, pink, grey, purple, yellow, orange)` во первых это просто названия переменных а не их значение. Во вторых нельзя чтобы id начинался с цифры.

```js
function change_color(e, col) {
  document.querySelector(e).style.backgroundColor = col;
  
}
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' class="container">
  <div id='n1' class="nav1"></div>
  <div id='n2' class="nav2"></div>
  <div id='n3' class="nav3"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='n4' class="nav4"></div>
  <div id='n5' class="nav5"></div>
  <div id='n6' class="nav6"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='n7' class="nav7"></div>
  <div id='n8' class="nav8"></div>
  <div id='n9' class="nav9"></div>
  <br/>
  
  <button onclick="change_color('#n1','red')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n2','blue')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n3','black')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n4','green')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n5','pink')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n6','grey')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n7','purple')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n8','yellow')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color('#n9','orange')">XXX</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему не выполнялись все 9 команд? Как интерпретируется, когда аргументы функции - константы?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka  выполнялись: `document.getElementById('2'...'9').style.background = undefined;`

Comment: Названия цветов JS константы ведь?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka да, но не параметры функции `red, blue, black, green, pink, grey, purple, yellow, orange`. сравните: `function change_color(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) {`

Comment: константы это объявляются через const

Comment: Должен был быть конфликт(в другом языке)

Comment: js очень мягок к кодеру, мягче даже чем питон

Answer (score 1):

```js
function change_color(id, color) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.background = color;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' class="container">
  <div id='1' class="nav1"></div>
  <div id='2' class="nav2"></div>
  <div id='3' class="nav3"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='4' class="nav4"></div>
  <div id='5' class="nav5"></div>
  <div id='6' class="nav6"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='7' class="nav7"></div>
  <div id='8' class="nav8"></div>
  <div id='9' class="nav9"></div>
  <br/>
  
  <button onclick="change_color(1, 'red')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(2, 'blue')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(3, 'black')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color(4, 'green')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(5, 'pink')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(6, 'grey')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color(7, 'purple')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(8, 'yellow')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(9, 'orange')">XXX</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете функцию, передавая ей один аргумент, попробуйте так.

```js
function change_color(id, color) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.background = color;
}
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' class="container">
  <div id='1' class="nav1"></div>
  <div id='2' class="nav2"></div>
  <div id='3' class="nav3"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='4' class="nav4"></div>
  <div id='5' class="nav5"></div>
  <div id='6' class="nav6"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id='7' class="nav7"></div>
  <div id='8' class="nav8"></div>
  <div id='9' class="nav9"></div>
  <br/>
  
  <button onclick="change_color(1, 'red')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(2, 'blue')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(3, 'black')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color(4, 'green')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(5, 'pink')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(6, 'grey')">XXX</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="change_color(7, 'purple')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(8, 'yellow')">XXX</button>
  <button onclick="change_color(9, 'orange')">XXX</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция

```
function change_color(id, color) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.background = color;
}
```

Кнопки

```
<button onclick="change_color('1', 'red')">XXX</button>
<button onclick="change_color('2', 'blue')">XXX</button>
.......
```